# Chrome developer toolsのCache StorageにAMPで作成したサイトのアセットが表示されないのはなぜでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

「AMPで作成したサイト」にサービスワーカーをインストールをしているにも関わらず、Chrome developer toolsのCache Storageにアセットが表示されないのはなぜでしょうか？

#### 【質問の補足】

上記【質問の主旨】に対して下記5点を補足説明します。

1.

【質問の主旨】にある「AMPで作成したサイト」は下記のURLで一般公開しています。
https://e-yota-ec.com/article.amp.html

2.

【質問の補足】1.のURLにアクセスして、Chrome developer toolsのCache Storageを確認すると、
"my-site-cache-v1"という任意で定義した、キャッシュ名は表示されるものの、アセットは表示されません。なおアセットをキャッシュするためにChrome developer toolsの[Service Workers]→[Application]→[Update on reload]にはチェックを入れています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3.

「AMPで作成したサイト」のコードはGitHubで公開しています。
https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota-ec.com/tree/developer_3

4.

【質問の補足】3.で公開しているコードでサービスワーカーに関連するファイル（sw.jsとsw-install.js）は、下記のGoogleの開発者ページをコピペしています（ただしsw.jsで定義した`urlsToCache`は除く）
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/

5.

【質問の補足】4.で紹介したGoogleの開発者ページでは[「つまずきやすいポイント」](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#_4)が紹介されています。

> 回避策は、`chrome://serviceworker-internals` にアクセスし、[Open DevTools window and pause JavaScript execution on service worker startup for debugging] にチェックを入れて、install イベントの開始時に debugger 文を記述してください。 これを、Pause on uncaught exceptions とともに使用すると、問題が明らかになります。

とありますが、ここに書かれていることやリンクが貼られている`Pause on uncaught exceptions`以降の説明がよく分かりません。

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: developer tools の console タブになんらかのエラーが吐かれていませんか。吐かれていたら質問文に追記してください。

Comment: ↑デモ環境の url あったんですね、すみません。おそらく `urlsToCache` の `'/'` のところで、トップページがなくて落ちてるんだと思います。 `'/'` を消すか、適当に index.html 作るかしたら期待する動作にならないでしょうか。

Comment: wataさん、コメントありがとうございます。[こちらのGitHub](https://github.com/echizenyayota/e-yota-ec.com/blob/developer_3/sw.js#L3-L4)に記述している通りにコードを修正してみましたが、アセットが表示されない状態です。

Comment: [一般公開url](https://e-yota-ec.com/article.amp.html) にて開発者ツールの「Network」タブを見ると、「home.png」と「Icon」が `404` と出ています。この辺をサーバーにアップしたら変わらないでしょうか。若干もぐら叩き感ありますから、`cache.addAll(urlsToCache);` のところを `urlsToCache.forEach(function (url) { cache.add(url).catch(function (e){ console.log("ERROR! : " + url); })});` と書くとエラーが出てる url を特定できると思います。

Comment: wataさん。コメントありがとうございます。
`cache.addAll(urlsToCache);`の代わりに教えていただいた`urlsToCache.forEach(function (url) { cache.add(url).catch(function (e){ console.log("ERROR! : " + url); })});`を実行すると、2つのことが分かりました。
1. `'/icons/home.png'`と`'/icons/Icon'`にエラーが発生すること。2. [こちらの画像](http://takaiba.net/stackoverflow/stackoverflow20190319_2.png)のとおり、iconsディレクトリ以外のアセットはすべて、Cache Strageに収められていること。[公式ドキュメント](https://mzl.la/2Y643y1)でCacheオブジェクトのメソッドを読んでいると、`add`と`addAll`では若干違うものの、とりあえずアセットがキャッシュされたので、Googleの公式ドキュメントにある[リクエストをキャッシュして返す](https://bit.ly/2ObldWB)以降を写経します。